# I want to create and automator that opens a specific file

Tags: automator

I want to open a specific file - if I press F5 or another key - its a file I use all the time, so want it to be open at a touch of a key

Comment: Does it has to be a key on a key board? Otherwise move the file in to the dock, so it is always there and opens with a click.

Answer (score 2):

Create a service like this and give it a shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services:

[image]

There's a bug in 10.7 and 10.8 where the shortcuts for services don't always work until you hover over the services menu from the menu bar. There is also a short delay before services are run, and the shortcuts don't work when the frontmost application doesn't have a services menu.

I use [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/):

[image]

In Alfred 2 hotkeys have a short delay unless you [change the trigger behavior](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/1136-slight-delay-between-hotkey-press-and-action/):

[image]

Comment: Hi Lauri. Does the free version have that functionality or only the powerpack?

Comment: @adayzdone It's only in the Powerpack, but some free alternatives are [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com) and [Launch it!](http://www.launchitapp.com).